# If an antiserum was raised in a buffalo by injecting it with monkey red blood cells, what would be the full name for this antiserum?

Tags: microbiology, immunology, homework

Im confused, i've attempted this & what i got is buffalo anti-monkey red blood cell antiserum. I'm not sure if this answer is right

Answer (score 1):

its actually **Anti-Monkey RBC Buffalo Antiserum** as the Ab formed is **Anti-monkey RBC Buffalo Ab.**